# Google Calendar: how many shared calendar can an app create?

Tags: calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have a project where I want to create calendars for a set of users.

*These calendars should be private to the users authorized to view/edit the calendar.*

Look at the **Google Calendar API**, this seems possible (i.e. App creates a calendar then registers users to it if I'm not mistaken)

Now, I may have many, many groups of users, and will need to create many calendars.

**I need to know how many of those shared calendars I can create.**
I have asked on Google Forum but got no answer. There is no information about quotas on Calendars in the docs... So, does anyone know if there is a limit to the number of calendars an App can create?

I don't want to build a system based on an API and later realize I can't grow!
If someone with experience with the Google Calendar API have input on how to do this, I'm also taker.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Did you check this link https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

Comment: I did not see this post, thanks for pointing it out to me. It is good to know some of the limitations, but that does not answer the question. 
The phrase 'If a user creates more than 25 new calendars within a short period of time, that user's calendar might go into read-only mode.' gives me hope that I can create several 1000's calendars, but there is no clear indication of what is 'short period of time' or if there is any kind of hard stop after so many calendars.

Comment: did you ever got more details on this?

Comment: i was able to create hundreds of calendars, bit haven't tried to check the limit.

Comment: Very curious on the same, any follow up to this question would be much appreciated. @MrE any update since your last response? Thanks

Comment: @Antoni4 sorry, dropped this project, and haven't had a chance to test the limits.